Set f a lower semicontinuous real function. If the set of points such that f(x)=c is dense. Then c is an upper bound for f(x) for all x?
Set $f$ lower semicontinuous real function.
Supose the set of x such that $f(x)=c$ is dense.
Then $f(x)<= c$ for all $x$ or $f(x) >= c$ for all $x$ ?
Im inclined to belive that its the second option. By the definition of lower semicontinuous.

Hi Gabriel, please, may you use the math mod around your equation using dollar or two dollars delimiations around math, introducing what iare your attempts, and precising your expression : because "$ \forall x, \ f(x) \leq c \ \text{or}\ \forall x f(x) \geq c$ " is different than "$\forall x, \  f(x) \leq c \ \text{or}  \ f(x) \geq c$"

You have so :
By the definition of lower semi-continuity :
$$ \liminf_{y\to x }f(y)\geq f(x) $$
Yet, $A \triangleq \{x\in \mathbb{R}, \   f(x)=c \}  $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ :
There exists a sequence of $A,(a_n)$ such that :
$$ \lim{a_n}=x$$
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N},f(a_n)=c $$
By the definition of the lower continuity in $x$.
$$\liminf_{y\to x} f(y) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left(\inf\,\{ f(y) : y \in \mathbb{R} \cap B(x,\varepsilon)\setminus\{x\} \}\right) $$
So putting $n$ variating in place of $\epsilon$. Why is it possible ? See the box.

 $$\liminf_{a_n \to x} f(a_n) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left(\inf\,\{ f(a_n) : a_n \in \mathbb{R} \cap B(x,\varepsilon)\setminus\{x\} \}\right) =f(c) $$

$$ \lim_{a_n \to x} \inf( \{f(a_n) , a_n \in [x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon] \} \geq f(x) $$
i.e.
$$c\geq f(x)$$
So
$$ \boxed{ \forall x \in\mathbb{R },  \ c \geq f(x)}$$

Thanks ! Whats the set E?

Yes, it is $\mathbb{R}$, I added correction

@GabrielCorrêa Please add you attempts in your question.
